# How to compare if the coordinates are equal to the original coordinates of an object

Tags: ios, swift, compare, coordinates

Can someone please help me??

Lets start with the main information: I created an app that has a 2 view and one is called InfoView. This InfoView is located off screen with the following code:

(Code Hide View)

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.3, options: [ ], animations: {self.InfoView.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width + 150}, completion: nil)
```

Its automatically moved when the app starts. I placed the Code Hide View on ViewDidAppear.

When the button Info is pressed the InfoView ease in from left to right to its original coordinates, (As I placed it on the storyboard with x=12 and y=20 and the Views size depends on the screen size). I use the following code to bring it back.

(Code Show View)

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ ], animations: {self.InfoView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width + 150}, completion: nil)
```

The InfoView has a button that when pressed hides the view (Code Hide View) once again so that its off screen.

My problem is that when I tryout the app if the Iphone receives a call (phone call or sms or etc), after the call had ended it would show the InfoView on screen and without pressing the Show View Code to run.
Ive then hidden the view with:

```
InfoView.Hidden = True
```

And when I run the Show View code it changes to false and when it hides it turns to true and so on. However now when I receive a call and after the call has ended One can't see the InfoView (Thats good) although If I press the show Info Button the InfoView will appear suddenly on screen and ease out the right side of the screen, making it unreachable (off screen).

My question is there a way to compare the InfoView coordinates so that if its on Screen (And I haven't called it, run the show View) it could be sent back off screen. Like with an if statement. for example like:

```
if InfoView == CGPoint(12,20).... //(Then Run Hide View)
```

(I know the if statement is wrong) And I do understand that I got to run that func in the app delegate in the applicationWillResignActive.

Please can someone help me, am I on the right track or can someone give me another solution. (Tell Me If I need to explain it better)

Answer (score 0):

You should compare it by below way. Do not comapre with hardcoded point.

```
if(InfoView.center.x > self.view.bounds.width)
{
    //infoview is hidden
}
else
{
    //infoview is visible
}
```

Comment: The issue is not if its hidden or visible. The issue is that when a call is received the InfoView location changes from being off screen on the left side to appear right on screen and if the func show InfoView runs it animates the view off screen to the right side.